# I am having trouble with a Predicate in JPA in inherited code

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have some inherited code that is using JPA and is supposed to return a list of all processes that include all listed chemicals - an AND operation. However, the list is always empty. The code that returns the processes that have any of the listed chemicals (OR) seems to be OK. JDK version is 1.7. Hibernate 5.0.2

I have tried looking at the Javadocs, tutorials on JPA and hibernate, etc. But none give me a good feel for the Predicate class.

```
final CriteriaBuilder cb = getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Process> cq = cb.createQuery(Process.class);
final Root<Constituent> constituentRoot  = cq.from(Constituent.class);
List<Predicate> clist - new ArrayList<Predicate>();
//chemical_id_list is a List of type Integer = List<Integer> passed to method.
//It contains all of the ids of the chemicals of interest.
for (Integer id: chemical_id_list) {
  clist.add(cb.equal(constituentRoot.get(Constituent_.chemical), id));
}

//Code in common with the OR operation, which works..
```

It seems to me that the cb.equal part of this code is wrong. Constituent_.chemical is an attribute of the Constituent class, not an integer, which is what the "id" parameter is. How could a chemical object ever be "equal" to an integer? Or am I completely misunderstanding something? Thanks for your time.

Here is what is in the Constituent class:

```
public class Constituent implements Serializable{

private int constituentId;
private String chemicalNotes;
private String  labelText;
private String quantity;
private int sort;
private Chemical chemical;
private Phase phase;
private Role role;
private Step step;

//getters and setters
}
```

Here is what is in the Chemical class:

```
public class Chemical
{
 private int chemicalId;
 private String boilingPoint;
 private String canonicalFormula;
 private String meltingPoint;
 private String name;
 private String notes;
//getters and setters
}
```

Here is what is in the Process class, although I do not show the use of it in the code here:

```
public class Process
{
   private int processId;
   private String name;
   private String notes;
   private List<Step> steps;
//Getters and setters not shown.
}
```

Comment: What is your version of JDK, Hibernate, JPA? What is `chemical_id_list`?

Comment: chemical_id_list is a List of type Integer. JDK is 1.7. JPA version - I am not sure and will take some time to find.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this query is that you join the `chemical` only once. Due to that, you check that the `id` of that 1 `chemical` is equal to all the `Integer` in your `List`. So, as soon as you `List` contains more than one `Integer`, the result set is empty.

You need a separate join for each chemical id that you want to check.

This query should return all `Constituent` that have all `Chemical`s identified by the `chemical_id_list`

```
final CriteriaBuilder cb = getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Process> cq = cb.createQuery(Process.class);
final Root<Constituent> constituentRoot  = cq.from(Constituent.class);
List<Predicate> clist - new ArrayList<Predicate>();
//chemical_id_list is a List of type Integer = List<Integer> passed to method.
//It contains all of the ids of the chemicals of interest.
for (Integer id: chemical_id_list) {
  Join<Constituent, Chemical> chemical = root.join(Constituent_.chemical);
  clist.add(cb.equal(chemical.get(Chemical_.id), id));
}
```

Comment: I added some info on the Process, Constituent, and Chemical classes in my answer if you want to fix the query. From your answer I'm still not sure exactly what is wrong, being a Hibernate/JPA newby. Thanks for your time.

Comment: At this point I only want to fix the cb.equal query, because this is where things go off track.

Comment: I wasn't able to write any formatted, multi-line code here. I updated my response.

Comment: Thorben Jannsen - When I insert line "Join<Constituent,Chemical> chemical =  root.join(Constituent_.chemical);" from your answer, then I get the error message "The method join(SingularAttribute<?super Process,Y>) in the type From <Process, Process> is not applicable for the arguments (SingularAttribute<Constituent,Chemical>)"